# NSXMLParser delegate methods not working in iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks, nsxmlparser

I am calling **SOAP API** and I got the response in the **XML** format , I tried to parse the **XML** by setting the **delegate**.My problem with the delegate methods which are not being called, here's my API called and parsing code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

NSDictionary *dictionary = @{@"mobileuser3":@"loginUser"};
[[WMAPIClient sharedClient] loginAPI:@"/01/wsdl/LoginUserService" withParameters:dictionary withSuccessBlock:^(id responseObject){
    NSXMLParser *XMLParser = (NSXMLParser *)responseObject;
    [XMLParser setShouldProcessNamespaces:YES];
    XMLParser.delegate = self;
    [XMLParser parse];
}withFailureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error Retrieving Data"
                                                        message:[error localizedDescription]
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
}];
}
```

And Here is the parser delegate methods

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{
NSString *ele = elementName;
NSLog(@"elementName = %@, qName = %@",elementName,qName);}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{
NSLog(@"string = %@", string);

}
 - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{
NSLog(@"elementName = %@, qName = %@",elementName,qName);
}

- (void) parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser{
NSLog(@"End");
}
```

Please help me to sort out the issue...Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you not get a crash? I haven't looked at the library but it seems unlikely that a parser is returned to you, so your success block should crash. Are you sure the response isn't parsed into a dictionary or array for you...

Comment: No, I am not getting any crash , I got the NSXMLParser object but while the method [xmlParser parse] called its showing incorrect xml format

Comment: `NSXMLParser *XMLParser = (NSXMLParser *)responseObject;` Is `responseObject` really a `NSXMLParser` object? You may want to do `NSXMLParser *XMLParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:responseObject]` if it's a `NSData`, or if it's a `NSString`, change it to `NSData` first.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand from your comments, you are having problem with the object type you received. `NSXMLParser` has few initializing methods and most common ones are `initWithData` and `initWithURL`.

Try to add these lines for fix ;

```
NSString *xmlString = responseObject.responseString;
NSData *xmlData = [xmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding];
```

then use `initWithData` option.